# What links an account whenever you sign in using Facebook or Google

Tags: authentication, oauth, google-oauth, facebook-oauth

So here's my question. Say you have a Gmail and Facebook and they both use the same email.

Now say you login an app using Facebook. Say you log out and log back in using Google. It should link to the same account from what I've seen. But what happens if you were to change your Facebook primary email?  Would it create new accounts whenever you login into old apps using Facebook?

I've been wondering this since I'm doing some oauth stuff. Would this create a big confusion with any accounts you made on apps using a Facebook login? (Since you changed the email) I assume that at this point you could still login to those accounts using your Google account since it is the email that was registered to your Facebook before changing it.

Or does the accounts on apps that you make using Facebook or Google to sign in depend on how the developers set up their back end whenever you create an account?

I'm just curious to how this works.

Comment: In general, you should only use IDs to identify users, not emails.